# Where can i find official list of all ICAO Docs published?

Tags: regulations, icao

ICAO Docs are very essential for pilots to completely understand a concept and it is increasingly difficult to find relevant resources in internet.
It would be better to know the list of Docs available and select the docs relevant to the subject and download and study accordingly.
Hence i would like to know the official list along with frequent updates if there any amendments to docs
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of International Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO) documents on the ICAO website at the following address:

https://elibrary.icao.int/explore;mainSearch=1

On this page, you will find links to all ICAO documents, organized by document type and category. You can also use the search function to find specific documents by keyword or document number.

Comment: Docs for eg. Doc-10066 are not available. I have checked this link earlier and it doesn't contain all the Docs.

Answer (score 1):

Go to icao.int -> Information Resources -> Publications -> Products & Services Catalogue (https://www.icao.int/publications/Pages/catalogue.aspx)

In this page, you'll find "Edition 20XX" (XX -Current Year) which means all the annexes and docs published before 20XX
At the bottom, you'll find "Supplements", Any Docs that has been amended or corrigendum issued in the current year-20XX will be issued as supplements

For eg. (This eg has been documented on 25.12.2022)
If you look at Page.60 of "Edition-2022" catalogue, you'll find Doc9718-Vol-2 latest edition is published in 2013
Whereas go to supplements-11 and check whether doc9718 has been amended in the current year and if you see, yes on page-2, doc9718 has been amended in 2022, so make sure you download the latest edition.

Steps to make sure you are downloading the latest edition:
1.Look in the catalogue to find the relevant doc that suits your subject under study
2.Check in the latest supplement to find any amendment/Corrigendum issued in the current year
3.Download/Purchase the latest edition of Doc.